# Accurate Georeferencing of ETRS89-Projected Image and Conversion

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-processing, georeferencing, geometry-conversion

I'm seeking assistance with georeferencing the attached image. The image indicates that it is projected in ETRS89, and I have obtained Northing and Easting coordinates by tracing the cross symbols on the map. However, I am facing difficulties in accurately converting these coordinates to X and Y coordinates, which are required for uploading the data into QGIS. The conversions I have attempted so far have resulted in coordinates that fall outside the intended areas.

[image]

Comment: Which CRS are you using?

Comment: WGS 84/ UTM zone 32N EPSG:32632

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: Use EPSG 31467.

---

Germany has a surprisingly huge number of "official" CRS for a rather small country.

Most used are

- 25832 (ETRS98 - UTM Zone 32N)
- 25833 (ETRS98 - UTM Zone 33N)

which are basically clipped UTM zones.

Those two also exist with leading zone digits (32 or 33 in front of the East-coordinate, hence eight digits for Easting)

- 4647 (ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (zE-N))
- 5650 (ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N (zE-N))

You can use the standard UTM zones, sure, but not when the drawing says "ETRS 89":

- 32632 (WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N)
- 32633 (WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N)

But there's also the "old" DHDN CRS, based on Gauss Kruger and using the Bessel-Ellipsoid from 1841 and with smaller stripes than UTM uses. You can distinguish those by the leading "strip number", hence seven digits for Easting.

- 5520 (DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 1)
- 31466 (DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 2)
- 31467 (DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3)
- 31468 (DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4)
- 31469 (DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 5)

In your case the Eastings are noted with seven digits, e.g. `3281300` - hence you need to use EPSG code 31467.

Comment: Hi Erik! Your detailed explanation was quite helpful. I've imported the coordinates into QGIS but they lie outside of the expected location (i.stack.imgur.com/MxWUl.jpg). I used the recommended EPSG code 31467. From the initial drawing/image provided in my question, the expected location is somewhere in Karstädt, a municipality in the Prignitz district, in Brandenburg, Germany.

Comment: Finally, this worked for me: 102359 (ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_33N_7stellen)